# Webpack 5: reloading/unloading Federated Modules

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-5, webpack-module-federation

I use logic similar to the following in order to dynamically load FMs for my app:

https://github.com/module-federation/module-federation-examples/blob/master/dynamic-system-host/app1/src/App.js#L16

However, say the remote version of an FM changes and I want to reload it in its entirety, or remove it from my app context altogether - is this even possible and what is the preferred pattern of doing so?

Comment: If I understand you correctly you want to "hot swap" a remote (no page refresh needed) when you get notified that a new version of it is available/deployed? Correct? I have the same issue and don't know how to solve this... Any findings regarding this on your side?

Answer (score 0):

I'm also looking into this "problem". However, please check out the example in [module-federation-examples/dynamic-system-host](https://github.com/module-federation/module-federation-examples/tree/master/dynamic-system-host). What is this example?

- app1 as host application with two buttons
- app2 with a module which exports `./Widgets`
- app3 with another module which exports `./Widgets`, too
- clicking 1st button in app1 loads the module "./Widgets" from app2
- clicking 2nd button in app1 loads the module "./Widgets" from app3

You can endlessly switch between the implementations.
This proves that you can overwrite a module dynamicly.

How to do a reload of the same module now?

Combine the above app1 with a cache buster on the module URL: `?version=:TIMESTAMP:`. This should in theory reload the same module again because the URL is different.